# Good Shared Hosting or VPS to Host DE Domain

Tags: vps, shared-hosting, dns-hosting

One of my client has a .de  domain. I have VPS from Linode and I am pretty happy with them. Domain is registered with godaddy. DE domains Name servers have some restrictions. I first try to move name server to Linode. I set TTL values accordingly but couldn't succeed with Linode. Then try to configure name server of godaddy with adding A and CNAME record to point my Linode VPS with no success. Now I have one option I look forward good VPS or shared hosting that have a name server works with de domains. I found a shared hosting but they dont have php-curl installed. If you ever hosted a de domain please share your experience.

Comment: You need to tell us precisely how you failed to add the A and CNAME pointing to your VPS in godaddy. There is no reason godaddy can't point to a linode VPS.

Answer (score 2):

If you purchased the .DE domain from GoDaddy, you should be able to use their nameservers. I believe the restrictions you speak of are for actually registering the domains, not where the nameservers are located. What issues were you encountering with GoDaddy? Was it throwing an error when you tried to add the records? If so, you should probably speak to their support.

Comment: Itried to use godaddy but it fails http://www.denic.de/en/background/nast.html

Comment: That link you sent seems to be checking for correct DNS settings, only after you've configured them. Have you configured it on GoDaddy's end yet? Did it give you any issues or error messages within GoDaddy?